# how do i call the function in specified period of time?

Tags: python, multithreading, deep-learning, mutex

I am trying to build a learner which will call the function and store the weights into the DB, now the problem is, it at least takes from 30 to 60 seconds to learn, so if i want to store i need to wait and i decided to call the function with threading timer which will call the function after specified time period,

Example of code:

```
def learn(myConnection):
    '''
    Derive all the names,images where state = 1
    Learn and Store
    Delete all the column where state is 1
    '''
    id = 0

    with myConnection:

        cur = myConnection.cursor()
        cur.execute("Select name, image FROM images WHERE state = 1")
        rows = cur.fetchall()

        for row in rows:
            print "%s, %s" % (row[0], row[1])

            name ='images/Output%d.jpg' % (id,)
            names = row[0]

            with open(name, "wb") as output_file:
                output_file.write(row[1])


            unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(name)
            unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

            # here i give a timer and call the function 
            threading=Timer(60,  storeIntoSQL(names,unknown_encoding) )
            threading.start()

            id += 1
```

the thing that did not work with this is that it just worked as if i did not specify the timer it did not wait 60 seconds it just worked normal as if i called the function without the timer, Any ideas on how i can make this work or what alternatives i can use ? ... PS i have already used time.sleep it just stops the main thread i need the Project to be running while this is training

Example of the function that is being called:

```
def storeIntoSQL(name,unknown_face_encoding):
    print 'i am printing'
    # connect to the database
    con = lite.connect('users2.db')
    # store new person into the database rmena
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        # get the new id
        cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Users ")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        newId = len(rows)+1            
        # store into the Database
        query = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES (?,?,?)"
        cur.executemany(query, [(newId,name,r,) for r in unknown_face_encoding])
    con
```

I was also told that MUTEX synchronization could help, where i can make one thread to work only if the other thread has finished it's job but i am not sure how to implement it and am open to any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use the `threading` library of python and implement a `time.sleep(60)` somewhere inside your function or in a wrapper function. For example

```
import time
import threading

def delayed_func(name,unknown_face_encoding):
    time.sleep(60)
    storeIntoSQL(name,unknown_face_encoding)

timer_thread = threading.Thread(target=delayed_func, args=(name,unknown_face_encoding))
timer_thread.start()
```

Comment: it works, thank you it is not stopping the whole program but and it still does not work the way i wanted, it first stores null values in the columns then stores the correct values in the following columns will try to find a way stop it but thank you.

Comment: also i  wanted to ask, time.sleep() stops the work only for the correct thread where i call it? because i was calling it before and it stopped all the thread from running

Comment: Yes in this case since time.sleep is called within a specific thread, it delays only that thread. Regarding the null values I think it has probably something to do with the rest of the code and not with the timer